# Capture screenshot: native API vs opengl

Tags: macos, winapi, opengl

In my program I am using Qt's function: `qApp->primaryScreen()->grabWindow(qApp->desktop()->winId(),x_offset,y_offset,w,h);`

But its a little bit slowly for a "main task". So I've collide with a question above. The program able to work under Windows and Mac OS X. I heard about opengl as nice screengrabber since it is closer to GPU than native API plus its a cross platform solution. This is the first knowledge I want to get: **Opengl as desktop screengrabber, is it real?** *I mean like a button "print screen".*

If it is, **how?**

If its not:

Windows: can you please give advice *how to*? BitBlt, GetDC, smthing like this?

Mac OS X: AVFoundation? Please, can you describe this or give some link about *how to* capture screenshot using this class? (Its a hard way since I know about Objective-C(++) almost nothing)

**UPDATE:** I read a lot about ways to capture screenshot. There are some knowledge:

1. Opengl (maybe) is real as screengrabber, but use it will be irrcorrect for this software. Btw, I don't care, if there is some solution I will accept it.

2. DirectX it is not a way to solve my problem since this software does not work under Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on @Zhenyi Luo's answer, here is a code snippet I have used in the past.

It also uses FreeImage for exporting the screenshot.

```
void Display::SaveScreenShot (std::string FilePath, SCREENSHOT_FORMAT Format){

    // Create Pixel Array
    GLubyte* pixels = new GLubyte [3 * Window::width * Window::height];

    // Read Pixels From Screen And Buffer Into Array
    glPixelStorei (GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glReadPixels (0, 0, Window::width, Window::height, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

    // Convert To FreeImage And Save
    FIBITMAP* image = FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBits (pixels, Window::width,
                                                        Window::height, 3 * Window::width, 24,
                                                        0x0000FF, 0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, false);

    FreeImage_Save ((FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT) Format, image, FilePath.c_str (), 0);

    // Free Resources
    FreeImage_Unload (image);
    delete [] (pixels);
}
```

Comment: Tryed your solution - downloaded freeimage, installed, copy/pasted code. This works like in previous message - only zeroes. Maybe I should remind: I need read pixels from desktop, like "print screen" button. Or maybe I don't know some features how to use it)

Answer (score 0):

glReadPixels(   GLint x,
    GLint y,
    GLsizei width,
    GLsizei height,
    GLenum format,
    GLenum type,
    GLvoid * data),  would read a block of pixels into client memory starting at location data.

Comment: Thank you for fast reply! I tryed use it, but I am not sure i did right:  `unsigned char pixels[4] = {0};glReadPixels(0,0,500,500,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,pixels);` . But I am always see that `pixels` filled by zeroes after `glReadPixels`. `glGetError` return 0.

Comment: you could only read one pixel by allocating a pixels with size 4, but your input is 500*500 pixels, what did you get by glReadPixels(0,0,1,1,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,pixels);

Comment: Edited! So, now I am still taking only zeroes.

Comment: [glReadPixels](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glReadPixels.xhtml): *"Values for pixels that lie outside the window connected to the current GL context are undefined."*

Comment: @IInspectable This sounds like the point of problem! Can I set somehow GL context or have it another way to define this values and get an image?